# AVPlayer show loading indicator while seeking is complete

Tags: swift, avplayer

When i seek to a certain position, `avPlayer` does not start playback right away instead, it takes some time to play the audio. I would like to display a loading indicator during this delay. I have tried implementing AVPlayer's KVO to no avail.

How can i find out whether the avPlayer is buffering or not when seeking to a specific time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party loader.
usually I use a hud for loader. you can try this if you want .

here is the GitHub link of the hud: https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD